# How can I include a CDATA section in a ConfigurationElement?

Tags: c#, configuration, configuration-files

I'm using the .NET Fx 3.5 and have written my own configuration classes which inherit from ConfigurationSection/ConfigurationElement.  Currently I end up with something that looks like this in my configuration file:

```
<blah.mail>
    <templates>
        <add name="TemplateNbr1" subject="..." body="Hi!\r\nThis is a test.\r\n.">
            <from address="blah@hotmail.com" />
        </add>
    </templates>
</blah.mail>
```

I would like to be able to express the body as a child node of `template` (which is the `add` node in the example above) to end up with something that looks like:

```
<blah.mail>
    <templates>
        <add name="TemplateNbr1" subject="...">
            <from address="blah@hotmail.com" />
            <body><![CDATA[Hi!
This is a test.
]]></body>
        </add>
    </templates>
</blah.mail>
```

Answer (score 5):

In your custom configuration element class you need to override method `OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement`.

Example:

```
public class PluginConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    public NameValueCollection CustomProperies { get; set; }

    public PluginConfigurationElement()
    {
        this.CustomProperties = new NameValueCollection();
    }

    protected override bool OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement(string elementName, XmlReader reader)
    {
        this.CustomProperties.Add(elementName, reader.ReadString());
        return true;
    }
}
```

I had to solve the same issue.

Comment: I don't think this works in .net 4.5. The exception is thrown before those overrides are hit.

Answer (score 4):

In your ConfigurationElement subclass, try overriding SerializeElement using XmlWriter.WriteCData to write your data, and overriding DeserializeElement using XmlReader.ReadContentAsString to read it back.